# UITesting just fails with no tests written without any more context

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ui-testing

I am new to UITesting, I haven't written any tests in UITesting base file. Still, it fails without any more context how to fix it? even its not showing red cross sign as it shows in unit test files.

I've created a new project and checked there, it works fine. I'm adding it in an existing project. Any settings I've to do to make it work in the schema?

Whereas Unit Tests works fine.

[image]

Comment: What is displayed in the console?

Comment: haven't received anything in console.

Comment: Well I soleved it by my side. Posting an answer in a minute.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, I solved this issue. Select your UI test target → build setting → remove other linker flags if set.

I am posting this, so other developers get help, in case they are receiving this error.

[image]